C++ I get error code 5 error when doing patch bytes in DLL injection
After DLL injection in C++, I get error code 5 when trying to NOP the bytes I want. I think this is an access permission error. What should I do for this? I tried to run the loader as administrator.
bool memory::patch_bytes(std::uintptr_t address, std::string_view string_bytes) noexcept {
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> bytes = string_to_bytes(string_bytes);
    void* dest = reinterpret_cast<void*>(address);
    DWORD old_protection = 0;

    if (!VirtualProtect(dest, bytes.size(), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &old_protection))
        return false;

    std::memcpy(dest, bytes.data(), bytes.size());

    return VirtualProtect(dest, bytes.size(), old_protection, &old_protection);
}

void patch_integrity_check() {
    std::uintptr_t integrity_check = memory::find_pattern("75 ? 85 c9 0f 84 ? ? ? ? 8d 5d");

    if (integrity_check == 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("integrity check pattern not found"); //success found

    if (!memory::patch_bytes(integrity_check, "90 90"))
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to patch integrity check"); //error code 5
}


this not related to dll-injection, c++, dll, ntdll. and absolute not clear from your code, where and how you get error

I am happy you got that error (most code that tries things like this are not benign), it means the OS told you you don't have enough rights to hack into the other process specifically not if it process is running under the system account.

@RbMm i get the error in path_integrity_check(). i had a more detailed debugging code and saw error code 5. i get failed to patch integrity check error and i want to nop the address i want to change the byte value. but it does not allow this.

@PepijnKramer not every dll injection is malignant. this project serves a good purpose.

@ErayEser That's why I say most :) Still you seem to be trying to modify the rights of a page with more stringent security attributes. So what process are you actually trying to modify and under which account does it run?

Most likely the error is because you are using the wrong function call. See the comments at the beginning of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualprotect.

i not view where you can get this error. VirtualProtect must not return it. and you not direct checj error in code
